# Problema al insertar valor de un array en BD

Tags: php, array, rutas

Este código no inserta la ruta en la base de datos.  En cambio inserta el valor cuando se pone en VALUES el array tal cual, asi; ".$array[0]." 
  Al hacer echo de la variable $ruta0 1, 2  imprime el valor. Dónde puede estar el fallo?

```
    <?php
include('conexion.php');

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$array= $_POST['images'];

$url ='files/';
$ruta0= $url.".$array[0].";
$ruta1= $url.".$array[1].";
$ruta2= $url.".$array[2].";


$sql= mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO tabla (title, description, img1, img2, img3 ) VALUES( '$title', '$description', '$ruta0', $ruta1, $ruta2);

?>
```

Comment: Prueba colocando $ruta1, $ruta2 entre comillas '$ruta1', '$ruta2'

Comment: puedes agregar el error que te da, eso nos ayudaria muchisimo

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de

```
( '$title', '$description', '$ruta0', $ruta1, $ruta2 );
```

lo cual es incorrecto, tienes que escribir lo siguiente:

```
(".$title.", ". $description.", ".$ruta0.", ".$ruta1.", ".$ruta2.")";
```

El problema es que estás insertando las variables como texto plano, por lo cual guarda en la base de datos ese texto (`$ruta1`) en lugar del contenido de la variable `$ruta1`.

Espero haberte ayudado, si tienes alguna duda dímelo, ¡un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sigue sin insertar , puse tal cual tu linea. $sql= mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO tabla (title, description, img1, img2, img3) VALUES(".$title.", ". $description.", ".$ruta0.", ".$ruta1.", ".$ruta2.")");

Comment: @MamenMaria en un comentario a tu pregunta JackNavaRow te dijo que por favor nos dijeras si te saca algún error, por favor informa eso añadiendo contenido a la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo consegui , inserta en la bd. Solo fue cambiar las comillas dobles por simples dentro de VALUES.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es inseguro, pues es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL.

Mostraré una solución basada en consultas preparadas.

Para más detalles, revisa la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-stmt.bind-param.html).

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');


/* chequear conexión */
if ($mysqli) {

    $sql="INSERT INTO tabla (title, description, img1, img2, img3 ) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $title, $description, $ruta1, $ruta2, $ruta3);

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $array= $_POST['images'];

    $url ='files/';
    $ruta1= $url.$array[0];
    $ruta2= $url.$array[1];
    $ruta3= $url.$array[2];

    /* Ejecutar la consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    printf("%d Fila insertada.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

    /* Cerrar recursos */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

}else{

    echo "Revisa la conexión a la BD";
}

?>
```